# Value of the series $\sum _{n=0}^\infty e^{-\lambda n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, exponential-function

Is it possible to calculate the value of
$$\sum _{n=0} ^ \infty e^{-\lambda n}$$
for $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$?

I have to premise that I don't know if this problem is solvable. It is easy to prove that the series converges (by integral comparison or asymptotic comparison between $e^{-\lambda n}$ and $n^{-2}$), but the difficult question is that is it possible to calculate the value of this series.

Comment: Geometric series with common ratio $e^{-\lambda}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $x= e^{-\lambda}$, your series is $\sum _{n=0}^\infty x^n= {1\over 1-x}$ =${1\over 1-e^{-\lambda}}$

Comment: Only when $\lambda>0$ obviously.